# Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::session while run ./yii

Tags: php, yii2

I want to run yii2 console command, then I test it with run this `./yii`

When I run `./yii` I got this response

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::session'

in /var/www/html/myweb/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:143

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/myweb/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(73): yii\base\Component->__get('session')
#1 /var/www/html/myweb/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid/Module.php(62): yii\di\ServiceLocator->__get('session')
```

Here is my `common/config/params-local.php`

```
return [
        'uploadPath' => __DIR__ .'/../../uploads/',
        'baseurl' => 'http://localhost/myweb/'
];
```

Here is my `common\config\params.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'no-reply@myweb.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'no-reply@myweb.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
];
```

Here is my `console\config\params-local.php`

```
<?php
return [
];
```

Here is my `console\config\params.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'no-reply@myweb.com',
];
```

Here is my `common\config\main.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],      
    ],
    'modules' => [
            'redactor' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
                    'uploadDir' => __DIR__ .'/../../uploads/konten',
                    'uploadUrl' => '/myweb/uploads/konten',
                    'imageAllowExtensions'=>['jpg','png','gif']
            ],

            'gridview' =>  [
                    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
            ]

    ],
];
```

Here is my `common\config\main-local.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'language' => 'en-US',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'id-ID',
    'components' => [
            'authClientCollection' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
                    'clients' => [
                            'google' => [
                                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
                                    'clientId'     => 'xxxxx-cppd86jm9qfrt77pc684pau01nilf261.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                            ],
                            'facebook' => [
                                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                                    'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
                                    'clientId'=> 'xxxxxx16917400',
                                    'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxx8d99ff80ce1f713424',
                            ],
                    ],
            ],

        'db' => [
                'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=192.168.0.106;dbname=mydb',
                'username' => 'dev',
                'password' => 'dev123',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'enableSchemaCache' => false,
                'schemaMap' => [
                  'pgsql'=> [
                    'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
                    'defaultSchema' => 'public2' //specify your schema here
                  ]
                ], // PostgreSQL
        ],

        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],

        'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
            //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function

            'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => 'iix70.hosting.com',
                    'username' => 'myuser',
                    'password' => 'mypass',
                    'port' => '465',
                    'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
        ],
        'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '../../messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'id-ID',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],


        ],
    ],
    ]
];
```

Looks like something wrong with my script.
Currently i'm using ubuntu.

**What should I do next in case to fix that?** so it should response with yii command list instead of error.

and what cause these error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include `params-local.php`.

Comment: The console application does not have a session I believe. A session involves a cookie and I do not believe the console application can handle that.

Comment: @topher in which file I should include `params-local.php`?

@MihaiP. then how to fix these error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

When you add a value to `common/config` folder files, configurations used in all applications like `backend`, `frontend`, `console`, `api` and others. So in advanced template, you must just add values which are related to all these applications. Based on [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-directories.md) `common` folder is *files common to all applications*. This picture shows it clearly:

[image]

For your problem, as others mentioned, you don't have any `session` in console, but you added or used this module in `common/config/params-local.php` and based on introduction of this answer, it will be used in `console/config/params-local.php` and you get an error :).

**Update:** Based on your updated question, your `common/config/main.php` file is:

```
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],      
    ],
    'modules' => [
            'redactor' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
                    'uploadDir' => __DIR__ .'/../../uploads/konten',
                    'uploadUrl' => '/myweb/uploads/konten',
                    'imageAllowExtensions'=>['jpg','png','gif']
            ],

            'gridview' =>  [
                    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
            ]

    ],
];
```

`gridviw` module, implicitly uses `session` for saving state of sorting. In other side you added this to `config` folder of `common`, so based on previous notes, it also will be used in `console` application. Console doesn't have `session` (and I think you don't need a grid view in your console :D) and it causes an error. For solving this problem, move this lines

```
   'modules' => [
                'redactor' => [
                        'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
                        'uploadDir' => __DIR__ .'/../../uploads/konten',
                        'uploadUrl' => '/myweb/uploads/konten',
                        'imageAllowExtensions'=>['jpg','png','gif']
                ],

                'gridview' =>  [
                        'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
                ]

        ],
```

to `main.php` of `frontend` or `backend` folder (based on your situations and use).

Comment: sorry I still didn't understand how to fix that, so I update my question with code in `params-local.php` and `params.php`

Comment: @DarkCyber So I think the problem is in your `common/config/main.php` or `common/config/main-local.php`. Can you attach them to your question? May you add `yii2-grid` module to `modules` section one of this files.

Comment: @DarkCyber Please see the updated answer. Don't hesitate to inform me if you have any problem about it.

Comment: @meysam updated the answer and it helped me too, as i was also getting the same problem , you need to move the module configuration of the kartik/gridview to the `frontend` and `backend` specific `config/main.php` files